# Usa Python requests library to download NOAA GFS and CFSV2 data

Tags: python-3.x, google-earth-engine, forecast, noaa

I'm using the following Python3 script to download [ncdc data from NOAA](https://www.ncdc.noaa.gov/cdo-web/webservices/v2#gettingStarted) using their friendly API.

```
req4 = 'https://www.ncdc.noaa.gov/cdo-web/api/v2/data?datasetid=GHCND&datatypeid=PRCP&limit=1000&stationid=GHCND:US1HIKI0020&startdate=2019-06-01&enddate=2019-07-22&units=metric'
r4 = requests.get(req4,headers={'token':Token})
d4 = json.loads(r4.text)
df = pd.DataFrame(d4['results'])
df

 attributes datatype    date                      station     value
0   ,,N,    PRCP    2019-06-01T00:00:00     GHCND:US1HIKI0020   0.0
1   ,,N,    PRCP    2019-06-02T00:00:00     GHCND:US1HIKI0020   0.0
2   ,,N,    PRCP    2019-06-03T00:00:00     GHCND:US1HIKI0020   1.0
3   ,,N,    PRCP    2019-06-04T00:00:00     GHCND:US1HIKI0020   1.0
4   ,,N,    PRCP    2019-06-05T00:00:00     GHCND:US1HIKI0020   0.5
```

This all works well and fine. 
Since I did not find, I'm wondering if there is a similar API to download data from [GFS](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/datasets/catalog/NOAA_GFS0P25) or [CFSV2](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/datasets/catalog/NOAA_CFSV2_FOR6H) just as appear in Google Earth Engine. Since this data is available in GEE, I hoped that it is also available using direct Python API.